# phonegap-plugin-push message not showing for android

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I'm using the following plugin for my notifications for Ionic 3 .

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.10.5">
```

For iOS im able to achieve multi-line by using this in my backend:

```
private static String iosMessage = "Test Alert Header\nTest Message";
 ApnsService service =
    APNS.newService()
    .withCert(PATH_TO_P12_CERT, CERT_PASSWORD)
    .withProductionDestination()
    .build();

String payload = APNS.newPayload()
  .alertBody(iosMessage)
  .sound("default")
  .build();
  service.push(DEVICE_TOKEN, payload);
  System.out.println("The message has been sent...");
```

For Android:

```
    private static String title = "Message Header";
    private static String message = "Message Text";
String pushMessage = "{\"priority\":\"high\",\"notification\":{\"title\":\"" +
            title +
            "\",\"message\":\"" +
            message +
            "\"},\"to\":\"" +
            DEVICE_TOKEN +
            "\"}";


    // Create connection to send FCM Message request.
    URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    // Send FCM message content.
    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(pushMessage.getBytes());

    System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
```

I'm unable to show "Message Text" which only "Message Header" appears in a single line notification.

I'm trying to achieve a multi line notification on Android. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `message` to `body`:

```
String pushMessage = "{\"priority\":\"high\",\"notification\":{\"title\":\"" +
            title +
            "\",\"body\":\"" +
            message +
            "\"},\"to\":\"" +
            DEVICE_TOKEN +
            "\"}";
```

Refer to here for the formatting:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

[image]

Comment: No wonder! A hindsight of my part not to check the body tag. Thanks!